# How do I set NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy for LINQPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I'm getting `NotSupportedException` when I use a legacy library from `LINQPad`. I found this exception is due to deprecation of `Code Access Security` in `.NET Framework`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191568(v=vs.110).aspx

So I add `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy>` to `LINQPad.config` file according to MSDN article, but it still causes an `Exception`. Adding the configuration element to `LINQPad.UserQuery.exe.config` helps me, but it seems to be regenerated on launching `LINQPad`.

Is there other way to add a configuration element for `LINQPad`?

(And why doesn't this element work in `LINQPad.config` ...)

Example (causes same `Exception`):

```
// Add reference for System.Security.dll and import namespace System.Security.
new HostSecurityManager().DomainPolicy
```

Comment: Did you put it under `configuration\runtime` as required? As shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Tamir yes. and I checked it works in same position of `LINQPad.UserQuery.exe.config`.

Comment: Try to put it inside the `LINQPad.exe.config` instead of inside the `LINQPad.config`. I don't remember if LINQPad opens a new process for the query and if not - that security restriction might be because you the restricted process is `LINQPad` itself.

Comment: @Tamir Latest LINQPad creates process for each queries by default and probably it is `LINQPad.UserQuery.exe`. However, disabling that behavior and putting the configuration inside `LINQPad.exe.config` seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy is unusual in that it must come from the config file for the process, not the AppDomain.

If you disable process isolation in LINQPad, a workaround is to put the setting into `LINQPad.exe.config` instead of `LINQPad.config`.

This workaround doesn't work with process isolation enabled, however this will be addressed in a LINQPad update (v5.05.04). A beta will be released shortly.

Comment: I've checked current beta (v5.06.1) and the setting in `LINQPad.exe.config` works with process isolation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since [`LINQPad` <strike>runs</strike> used to run each query in a new `AppDomain` and not in a new `Process`](http://www.linqpad.net/howlinqpadworks.aspx), I assume the 'restricted' program is `LINQPad.exe` itself:
<sub>(I dont know which version of `LINQPad` is used so thats a possible solution.)</sub>

[image: LINQPad AppDomains]

`LINQPad` loads its own configuration from `LINQPad.exe.config`, try adding the required configuration to it instead of the `LINQPad.config` file - which is the query configuration file.

Also, make sure you have a [right configuration hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253(v=vs.110).aspx):

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true|false"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The asker didn't say which version of `LINQPad` he uses and in fact it solved the problem for him...

Comment: I'm using LINQPad5、but latest version of LINQPad4 also uses `LINQPad.UserQuery.exe`. So your solution won't work without disabling `LINQPad.UserQuery.exe`. However, why I should place the option in `LINQPad.exe.config` not `LINQPad.config`.helps me. Thanks!